# Why is 'New' being called for each record retrieved when using the entity Framework

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I have been seeing some odd behaviour in an entity that I have for which I created a partial class to override the ToSting Method and provide some basic property setting when a new instance of that entity is created (for example I might set an order date to 'Now') in a constructor.

This odd behaviour led me to look closely at the partial class and I was surprised to see that even when a set of pre existing records was being retrieved the constructor was being called for each retrieved record.

below is a very simple example of what I might have:

```
Partial Public Class Product


Public Sub New()

    CostPrice = 0.0
    ListPrice = 0.0 

End Sub
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return ProductDescription
End Function
End Class
```

I have two questions that arise from this:

1) is this normal behaviour in the Entity Framework if you add a partial class to which you add a constructor?

2) if not then I must assume that I have done something wrong, so what would be the correct way to 
override the constructor to do things similar to the example I mentioned above?

Thanks for any insights that you can give me.

This is using EF 5.0 in a vb project

Comment: The constructor is _always_ called when an object is created.

Answer (score 1):

think to the sequence of events leading to the retrieval of an entity from the database. Basically it should be something like:

- query the database
- for each row of the query result give an entity

The giving is then as follow for each retrieved row:

- create a new instance of the retrieved entity
- populate this new instance with the value of the row

Well with each instance creation, the constructor is called.

I think you are mixing:

- instance initialization where you "allocate" the object, and
- business initialization where you enforce business logic

both may be done, at least partially, in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you.  What you say makes a great deal of sense and begs the obvious question, in that case how does one differentiate between initialisation when one allocates an existing object that already exists in the database and the initialisation of one that does not?

Comment: Usually one use a "factory" pattern. Basically you have a static method that gives you a new and correctly initialized instance of the object. Something like `public static SomeType GetNewSomeType() {SomeType o = new SomeType(); o.Property1 = someValue; return o;}`. I wrote something about [this](http://madbuildertools.blogspot.fr/2011/08/managing-default-values-for-entities-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

`new` is always called when a class is first instantiated and if you do not explicitly declare a constructor then a [default constructor will be created by the compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173115%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Unless the class is static, classes without constructors are given a public default constructor by the C# compiler in order to enable class instantiation.

When defining POCO classes for Entity Framework the class must have a default constructor and EF will always call this *default* constructor whether you have explicitly defined it or the compiler did it for you.

If for any reason you have need to pass anything into the class when it is instantiated you can [use the `ObjectContext.ObjectMaterialized` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.objectmaterialized.aspx).